# If I need to group or filter by a calculated column in sql, I have to specify the calculation twice. Does this mean double the SQL Server work?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a basic SQL query where I do some math or other column transformations.

```
SELECT
    (firstname +'.'+ lastname) AS fullname, COUNT(*) AS recordCount
FROM 
    people
GROUP BY 
    (firstname +'.'+ lastname)
```

So if I run it on this table

```
firstname, lastname
john, smith
john, smith
john, smith
jane, smith
jane, smith
```

It might return output like this:

```
fullname,   recordCount
john.smith, 3
jane.smith, 2
```

In doing the above, in the query it looks like I'm calculating `(firstname +'.'+ lastname)` twice. Does this double the load on SQL Server, or is SQL smart enough to recognize I'm doing the same operation and just evaluate it once? Would it be better to do the calculation in a subquery like below?

```
SELECT
    fullname, COUNT(*)
FROM
    (SELECT (firstname +'.'+ lastname) AS fullname 
     FROM people)
GROUP BY 
    fullname
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Currently I'm working in databricks, which I believe is sparksql, but I know I've run into a similar problem with other sql types as well -- I would have guessed this was a flavor agnostic problem?

Comment: Different products optimize in different ways. You can probably find both versions here.

Comment: No modern database will evaluate that expression twice. And even if it did, I am pretty sure the overhead is not noticeable with any real world sized table because all the other work will overshadow that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's great to know :) Of course, this is just a simple example, I'm sadly doing... less efficient operations, operations that might rhyme with flegex.

Answer (score 0):

Your database looks like SQL Server.  If so, SQL Server supports lateral joins, which can be expressed using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT v.fullname, COUNT(*) AS recordCount
FROM people p CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (p.firstname +'.'+ p.lastname)) v(fullname)
GROUP BY v.fullname;
```